# What are the areas of mathematics philosophers deal with primarily?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Is it just discrete mathematics? I keep seeing symbols used in discrete mathematics on this stackexchange site. Is there any other area or is it just discrete mathematics, also what are the subfields of discrete mathematics, philosophers primarily deal with?

Comment: You've tagged your question with "philosophy of mathematics", but that's not the same thing as "areas of mathematics philosophers deal with" - philosophers might *use* the language of mathematics and/or logic (not necessarily appropriately) even when they're not discussing the philosophy of mathematics. The latter discusses such things as "In what sense do mathematical objects 'exist'?" (or "Is maths discovered or invented?"), "What constitutes mathematical 'proof'?", "Should a proof critically rely on the use of LEM?" and so on.

Comment: Foundations, that is parts of mathematical logic and set theory that are seen as a way to "justify" mathematics and "reveal" what it is "really" about, see [SEP, Philosophy of Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/) that reflects this narrow focus. There is a minority that criticizes it and advocates philosophy that reflects on structure of more modern advanced areas, like algebraic geometry, algebraic topology, quantum algebra and so on. [Corfield's Towards a Philosophy of Real Mathematics](https://www.ams.org/notices/201110/rtx111001454p.pdf) is a review.

Comment: You have it backwards: discrete mathematics has something in common with deductive reasoning which interests philosophers. Discrete mathematics is a specialty in the field of mathematics--not part of philosophy. There are techniques of reasoning that discrete mathematics doesn't cover at all. So understand that mathematics is not the ultimate field for truth in reality. Mathematical logic is what you are speaking on bit people hide this name for some reason. All modern logic is part of Mathematical logic due to the use of those common symbols. There are other methods besides this one field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major overlap of Philosophy with Mathematics is in symbolic logic.

I am not sure I consider logic to be part of discrete mathematics.  The study of things like the models of Real Closed Fields are part of the field.  So is the consideration of infinitesimals and other nonstandard elements.  Those are clearly continuous math.  If you want to look at Intuitionism, alternative models of continuity are a major component of mathematics that requires reconstruction if you want to avoid objectified infinities.  The biggest problems faced by approaches like Constructivism or Ultra-Finitism is working around all the implicit infinity in Analysis.  You can even go all the way back to Zeno, and say that philosophy was weighing in on the contradictions implicit in continuous mathematics before we had invented real numbers.  One of Kant's Antinomies is superficially about atomism, but is ultimately also about the two contradictory characterizations of the continuum in terms of continuous geometry and in terms of points.

Philosophy of Mathematics covers all of mathematics.  There is no point in separating out specific domains.  The ontological and epistemological questions apply just as much to real analysis or abstract algebra as to the integers.  And those different domains affect the discourse differently.  The simplest examples are discrete, and this is not a deeply specialized forum, so you may see mostly discrete examples.  But that is not representative of the field as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Many areas of mathematics interest philosophers. These include (no doubt among others):

- its existential status (ontology) - did maths exist before there were mathematicians, does it even exist in some Ideal realm independent of the physical Universe?
- its formal nature, as a branch of formal logic (though many mathematicians will argue that formal logic is a branch of mathematics)
- its application to the physical world through the laws of science (is an equation such as *F=ma* just a model for our understanding or is it a fundamental aspect of Nature?)

Interest in discrete mathematics came to the fore in the twentieth century for two reasons.

First, philosophers such as Bertrand Russell became much taken with axiomatic set theory as the foundation of all reason. Everything from baskets of apples to numbers to words could be placed into sets and logically manipulated. But to build a set of items, you need identifiable, i.e. discrete, items.

Then, along came digital computers, their binary logic embodying the essence of discrete or yes/no logic. The Boolean logic of their circuitry had originally been devised by a philosopher and the circuit output states are to this day defined by "truth" tables.

Journals such as *Discrete and Computational Geometry* abounded.

Set theory failed in its century-long bid to conquer the world (though many mathematicians and philosophers are still adherents), while discrete mathematics remains important in computation theory and therefore of current interest to a great many philosophers.